# Force Shortcut onto a fixed Desktop/Start Menu of a single PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, shortcut

We have folder redirection setup for our users through GPO but I need for one PC to include a  couple of shortcuts in the start menu or on the desktop. The folders are loaded from a server path. Is it possible to set that up on the machine or will I have to create separate policies for that PC/User?

Comment: Do you need the shortcuts available on a per-machine, or per-user basis?  If you want the same additional shortcuts for every user on the machine, you may be able to use the "All Users" folder on XP, or "Public" folder on Vista/Win7/Win8 to do this.

Comment: I've tried using the Public folder and no luck there. Not sure if that is restricted by policy or not but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Since the Start Menu and Desktop paths use folder redirection, you can't change it on one specific computer.  The user gets their Start Menu and Desktop on any machine they log into.

Your options are basically to set up another user account (you could set up a local account on the specific computer in question) or setup a GPO or script that only applies to the existing user on the specific computer in question.

If you're using a GPO, you could set up a GPO to add those two shortcuts, and then use the Security Filtering option to make it only apply to the specific user and the specific computer you want.

Comment: You used to be able to place shortcuts in the "All Users" folder (now called "Public" folder) and roaming profile users would still load these shortcuts on a per PC basis in addition to their own shortcuts.  Has this behavior changed?

Comment: @jlehtinen You should make that a comment on the question - I may have misread it, but am under the impression that the shortcuts in question are for a specific user on a specific computer, which would rule out using the All Users/Public folder.